# Clipping the EO.WebControl, WPF & C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, browser, clip

I am trying to positioning EO.WebBrowser.Wpf.WebControl using .NET 4.5. It is one of WPF webbrowsers from NuGet. For some reasons, I need the instance of that webbrowser to be bigger than its parent object. My expectation was, that it is possible to clip it with the parent by something like this:

```
WebControl Browser = new WebControl() 
{ 
    ClipToBounds = true
};
```

Unfortunately, it is not working. For illustration following pictures (sorry for the links, but I don't have rights to send images directly):

http://unsite.cz/StackOverflow/7XJrP.png

http://unsite.cz/StackOverflow/DHwud.png

On the picture, there is used red System.Windows.Controls.Border to highlight the problem. Left and top part is OK, but bottom and right not, beacause the browser overflows its bounds. The hierarchy used for illustration is **Window > Border > ScrollViewer > WebControl**. 
I tried to place some panels between ScrollViewer and Webcontrol, but without results.
I also tried to manipulate the Z-Index with no influence on it.

My last try was to solve this problem by following extern function for clipping:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern Int32 SetWindowRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn, Boolean bRedraw);
```

The function is OK when I clipping whole window, but I don't know (and I think that it is not possible) to clip with it just one specific WPF window descendant.

So here is my question: How to force EO.WebBrowser.Wpf.WebControl to autoclipping, or how to do it manually?

Thanks

P.S. Sorry for my english...